# Test on Publishing my own python package to PyPI but failed

Tags: python, pypi

I followed the instructions [here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to publish a simple project onto PyPI. I succeeded after some struggles.

However, after I installed the project thru `pip install my-project`, I cannot import it in Python like this: `ImportError: No module named my-project`...

Is it because of my file structure? It is like this:

My-project-folder

|- setup.py

|- test.py

|- README

|- my-project

~~|- file.py

~~|- file2.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `__init__.py` inside `my-project`!

Comment: Yes! That is it! You are awesome!